# jQuery AJAX send multiple API calls on keyup. How to avoid it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

The `maxlength` attribute of an input text `(#gtin)` has been defined to 14.

The following code is making 2 calls to an API when I `paste (CTRL+V)` `values (with length = 14)` into the input. However, if I type the values manually, there is only one call once length equals 14:

```
$('#gtin').on('keyup',function(){

  if($("#gtin").val().length > 13) {
    var gtin = $("#gtin").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.priceapi.com/products/single?token=*Masked*&country=de&source=google-shopping&currentness=daily_updated&completeness=one_page&key=gtin&value=' + gtin,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            console.dir(json);
        }
     });

 }

});
```

I assume that `CTRL + V` `counts` as 2 `keyups`, and therefore, the double call occurs. Is therefore a more intelligent way to make the API call when the defined input's length is equal 14? Which is the best way to bypass multiple calls if, f.i., someone keeps typing keys although the input's `maxlength` has been reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly solution but will do it...

```
var ajaxRequestMade = false;
$('#gtin').on('keyup',function(){
  var len = $("#gtin").val().length;

  if (len > 13 && !ajaxRequestMade) {
    ajaxRequestMade = true;
    $.ajax(...);
  }
  // Optionally reset it
  if (len < 14) {
    ajaxRequestMade = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer (in combination with @Rudis one) helped to get it done!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the event is fired by the `ctrl` key:

```
$('#gtin').on('keyup',function(e){

    if (!e.ctrlKey) {

        // Your ajax call

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making two function calls with `$("#gtin").val()` you may want to use `this.value`. The context herein `this` is your `input` box as long as you do not change it by binding another object to your unknownimous function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var f = 1;
    var val='';
    $('#gtin').on('keyup',function(e){
        if($(this).val() != val || e.which == 86 && $(this).val() == val)
        {
            f=1;
        }
        if($("#gtin").val().length > 13 && f==1) {
        var gtin = $("#gtin").val();
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.priceapi.com/products/single?token=*Masked*&country=de&source=google-shopping&currentness=daily_updated&completeness=one_page&key=gtin&value=' + gtin,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json) {
                    f=0;
                    val = btn.val();
                    console.dir(json);
                }
             });
            }
        });
```